# Sort data by key (first and last) including all data between first and last key

Tags: pandas, sorting, append

I want to sort the data by key (first and last) but result should include all of the data between the first and last key not only unique data.

I have data:

```
ID  Data
ID1 40
ID2 43
ID3 45
    43
ID1 34
    57
ID3 58
ID4 65
    23
ID2 46
    90
ID4 87
ID1 65
    54
ID3 11
ID4 23
    43
    56
ID3 76
ID4 87
```

I use code:

```
import csv

macs = []
with open('EXAMPLE.csv', 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for row in reader:
        flag = 0
        for macs_i in macs:
            if macs_i[0] == row[0]:
                macs_i.append(row[1])
                flag = 1
                break

        if flag == 0:
            macs.append([row[0],row[1]])
print(macs)
```

the current result is like this :

```
ID1 40  34  65              
ID2 43  46                  
ID3 45  58  11  76          
    43  57  23  90  54  43  56
ID4 65  87  23  87
```

but my expected result:

```
ID1 40  43  45  43  34  57  58  65  23  46  90  87  65              
ID2 43  45  43  34  57  58  65  23  46                              
ID3 45  43  34  57  58  65  23  46  90  87  65  54  11  23  43  56  76
ID4 65  23  46  90  87  65  54  11  23  43  56  76  87
```

please help me, 
thank you for your answer

Comment: what do you mean by **key(first and last)**?

Comment: for my data, it means key (ID) first and last appearance. For example ID1 first (40) and last (65).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC

```
s=df.reset_index().groupby('ID')['index'].agg(['min','max'])
s.apply(lambda x : pd.Series(df.Data.iloc[x['min']:x['max']+1].values.tolist()),1)
Out[221]: 
       0     1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9     10    11  \
ID                                                                            
ID1  40.0  43.0  45.0  43.0  34.0  57.0  58.0  65.0  23.0  46.0  90.0  87.0   
ID2  43.0  45.0  43.0  34.0  57.0  58.0  65.0  23.0  46.0   NaN   NaN   NaN   
ID3  45.0  43.0  34.0  57.0  58.0  65.0  23.0  46.0  90.0  87.0  65.0  54.0   
ID4  65.0  23.0  46.0  90.0  87.0  65.0  54.0  11.0  23.0  43.0  56.0  76.0   
       12    13    14    15    16  
ID                                 
ID1  65.0   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  
ID2   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  
ID3  11.0  23.0  43.0  56.0  76.0  
ID4  87.0   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
```

Comment: @AriefHidayat yw~ happy coding